# How many subsets are there for this case?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question: You are given $20$ sugar bars (B$_{1}$, B$_{2}$, ..., B$_{20}$) and $50$ salt bars (S$_{1}$, S$_{2}$, ..., S$_{50}$). Consider subsets of these $70$ bars, that contain at least $3$ sugar bars (and any number of salt bars). How many such subsets are there?

(Answer: $1.18 \times 10^{21}$)

Attempt: Since it is at least $3$ sugar bars, it should start the count at $\dbinom{20}{3}$ all the way to $\dbinom{20}{20}$. For the salt bars, since it is any number of combinations, it should be $2^{50}$. I just multiplied them out using product rule but I didn't get the correct answer. How should I proceed with this?

Comment: On this site, we use a type of $\LaTeX$ called MathJax. Search for a tutorial on it. Please use it in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total number of subsets is $2^{70}$. consider those that have less than 3 sugar bars, $\binom{20}{2}2^{50}+\binom{20}{1}2^{50}+2^{50}$. so we should get $2^{70}-\binom{20}{2}2^{50}-\binom{20}{1}2^{50}-2^{50}$. I hope I got this right!

Comment: It's hard to tell precisely how close to being right you are:
\begin{align}
2^{70} -\dbinom{20}{2} 2^{50} -\dbinom{20}{1} 2^{50} -2^{50} &=1.1804 \times 10^{21}; \\
2^{70} -\dbinom{20}{2} 2^{50} &=1.1804 \times 10^{21}; \\
2^{70} -2^{50} &=1.1806 \times 10^{21}; \\
2^{70} &=1.1806 \times 10^{21};
\end{align}
But your reasoning seems legit.

Comment: I think what you did makes a lot of sense to me! This should be right! :)